# How to know which device tree my phone uses?

Tags: rom, xiaomi, device-firmware

The boot.img contains lots of device tree files. 15 for my Poco M3. They are all variations of the same name but with some different properties. Anyways, how do I know which one of them my phone picks?

I decompiled them but it's not obvious, they are different bya  little:

```
model = "Qualcomm Technologies, Inc. Bengal 1Gb DDR HD+ SoC";
model = "Qualcomm Technologies, Inc. Bengal 2Gb DDR HD+ SoC";
```

but my phone does not have 2gb of RAM, it has 4gb, and there's no 4gb file. So, how does the phone pick the right one?

Comment: is *'ls -ld /proc/device-tree'* of any use?

Comment: @alecxs `citrus:/ $ cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/model                         
Qualcomm Technologies, Inc. BENGAL IDP` this model isn't in any of the decompiled .dtb files of the boot.img